# How can I adjust the display of IO ports on a subsystem block in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, port, simulink

I'm developing an 8-input digital multiplexer in Simulink and created a subsystem which implements a multiplexer operation with 3 enable inputs.

I would like to display the input channels (`I0-I7`) on the left of the subsystem block, the 3 enable inputs (`S0-S2`) on the bottom of the subsystem block, and the output port on the right of the subsystem block, like this:

```
           --------------
          |              |
  I0----> |              |
  I1----> |              |
  I2----> |              |
  I3----> |              |------>X
  I4----> |              |
  I5----> |              |
  I6----> |              |
  I7----> |              |
           --------------
              ^   ^   ^
              |   |   |
              S0  S1  S2
```

However, in Simulink the block is always displayed with *all* the input ports on one side and *all* the output ports on the opposite side.

Does anyone have any ideas for how I can display input ports on more than one side? Having all my input ports on one side makes it harder to visually distinguish them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a [Mux](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/mux.html) (or perhaps a [bus](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/buscreator.html)) signal to collect the input channels into just one input. With fewer inputs, it will be easier to distinguish them if they are all on the same side. Also, don't forget to [label your input ports](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/configure-a-subsystem.html).

Comment: Thanks, For now, I am using a bus and labelling them. Thanks a ton for your input.

Comment: The `PortConnectivity` property is read-only. `set_param` doesn't work on it.